# Why can't my Qt compile script work on macOS?

Tags: c++, bash, macos, qt, clang

I just started learning Qt few days ago.
Here is my Hello World:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel label( QLabel::tr("Hello Qt!") );
    label.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

To compile it without Qt Creator, I wrote a short compile script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
filename="$(pwd | awk -F "/" '    {print $NF}')" # get name of current directory
qmake -project
qmake $filename.pro
echo 'QT += core gui widgets' >> $filename.pro
make
open $filename.app
```

but the script does not work:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -headerpad_max_install_names  -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.12 -Wl,-rpath,@executable_path/../Frameworks -o qttest.app/Contents/MacOS/qttest helloqt.o   -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.2/lib -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework AGL
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QApplication::exec()", referenced from:
      _main in helloqt.o
  "QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)", referenced from:
      _main in helloqt.o
  "QApplication::~QApplication()", referenced from:
      _main in helloqt.o
  "QLabel::staticMetaObject", referenced from:
      _main in helloqt.o
  "QLabel::QLabel(QString const&, QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)", referenced from:
      _main in helloqt.o
  "QLabel::~QLabel()", referenced from:
      _main in helloqt.o
  "QWidget::show()", referenced from:
      _main in helloqt.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [qttest.app/Contents/MacOS/qttest] Error 1
The application cannot be opened because its executable is missing.
```

however, if I run the commands **separately**, it worked and `make` won't show any errors.

Why is that? What should I do in order to make the script work?

Comment: It works fine on linux.

Comment: idk why the SCRIPT can't apply on mac...... If I run the script command by command it'll work fine too......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obvious that there's a link problem here.

A random guess: in your shell, you append `QT += core gui widgets` to `*.pro` (which is used to link the lib I guess) **after** `qmake` it. So possibly it is not correct? Could you please try put `qmake $filename.pro` after `echo ... > $filename.pro`?

You shell:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
filename="$(pwd | awk -F "/" '    {print $NF}')" # get name of current directory
qmake -project
qmake $filename.pro # anchor A
echo 'QT += core gui widgets' >> $filename.pro # anchor B
# try exchange A and B?
make
open $filename.app
```

Comment: thanks, now it works. A question: why the original script works when I paste the commands line by line directly into the shell?

Comment: @Andy Chen idk, but I think there might be 2 possible reasons. 1. Is your terminal shell `bin/bash`? 2. Shell script on MacOS executes some commands non-blockingly.